# PostgreSQL throws error: could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1453875850": Too many open files

Tags: postgresql

I am running a postgres 16 container on docker compose, and lately, after splitting a 90GB DB into about 50 smaller ones, in my app side, I started to get errors like:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1453875850": Too many open files
```

Any idea what is going on and how can I bypass this problem?

Thanks!

The postgres image I'm using is : groonga/pgroonga:3.1.7-debian-16

My docker compose file definition is:

```
mw-db:
    image: 192.168.1.2:82/pgroonga:latest
    shm_size: 1g
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: 14
          memory: 50G
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
    networks:
      mw-network:
        aliases:
          - mw-db
      default: {}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /db:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
```

Complete stack trace:

```
2024-02-08T19:53:01.923Z <> {thread=update-search-table-monitor-thread} ERROR: [com.kp.mw.services.PopulateDBService] com.kp.mw.services.PopulateDBServicerlf(Failed to update search for SearchUpdateDBO(productId=10947c19-5740-4edf-b3dd-f7f9e7251e2c)) 
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1209666166": Too many open files
### The error may exist in com/kp/mw/db/mappers/TagsMapper.xml
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT t.id, t.value, t.locale, pt.username, pt.creation_time FROM tags t         JOIN products_tags pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id         WHERE pt.product_id = ?         AND t.locale = ?
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1209666166": Too many open files
; ERROR: could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1209666166": Too many open files
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:266) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.1.jar!/:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:107) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.1.jar!/:6.1.1]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:92) ~[mybatis-spring-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:439) ~[mybatis-spring-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy121.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:224) ~[mybatis-spring-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:141) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy163.getProductTags(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.kp.mw.services.PopulateDBService.updateProductSearch(PopulateDBService.java:1967) ~[!/:?]
    at com.kp.mw.services.PopulateDBService.updateSearchBatch(PopulateDBService.java:2279) [!/:?]
    at com.kp.mw.services.PopulateDBService$7.run(PopulateDBService.java:2262) [!/:?]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1209666166": Too many open files
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:177) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:?]
    at io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.jdbc.internal.OpenTelemetryStatement.wrapCall(OpenTelemetryStatement.java:294) ~[opentelemetry-jdbc-1.32.0-alpha.jar!/:1.32.0-alpha]
    at io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.jdbc.internal.OpenTelemetryPreparedStatement.execute(OpenTelemetryPreparedStatement.java:70) ~[opentelemetry-jdbc-1.32.0-alpha.jar!/:1.32.0-alpha]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:65) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:80) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:65) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:336) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:158) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:110) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:90) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:154) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:142) ~[mybatis-3.5.14.jar!/:3.5.14]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[?:?]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:425) ~[mybatis-spring-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: For docker compose it will be require to pass:  ulimits:
    nofile:
      soft: "65536"
      hard: "65536"